# Android AsyncQueryHandler for SQLite CRUD

Tags: android, sqlite, asynchronous, crud, loader

I'm trying to upgrade my database access by setting it up on an asynchronous task.
Finally I stuck at using [AsyncQueryHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.html). I did not find out much about this class but [this](http://www.trustydroid.com/blog/2014/10/07/using-asyncqueryhandler-with-content-provider/) is one of the tutorials I've read.
The author wrote not too much detail, what are the differences and advantages between a [Loader](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) and an AsyncQueryHandler. At the end he says:

> 1) Data is static. If a change happens to the underlying datasource,
>   you won't receive any update - that is a major drawback of
>   AsyncQueryHandler approach and a huge advantage of Loader API. Still,
>   there are workarounds - you may register a ContentObserver to your
>   ContentResolver... but that's another tale.

This confuses me a lot! What does that mean? I have to CRUD* data in my database dynamically. What shall I do?

(*) CRUD: **C**reate - **R**ead - **U**pdate - **D**elete

Comment: `Loaders` give you background loading for `R` only, `AQH` gives you background processing not only for `R` but also for `CUD`, if you need whole `CRUD` in the background choose `AQH`

Comment: @pskink Ok. And can you give a statement to the quote above?

Comment: do you have `ContentResolver#notifyChange` calls in your custom `ContentProvider`(in `CUD` cases)?

Comment: im not using contentprovider

Comment: hmmm err? the whole idea of `AQH` is to call some `ContentProvider`, see http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/AsyncQueryHandler.java#95

Comment: @pskink I extended my own SQLiteOpenHelper. Thats all.

Comment: but how do you want to use it with `AQH`?

Comment: @pskink I just want to upgrade it to async

Comment: this is what `AQH` is for, but with a custom  `ContentProvider`

Comment: @pskink But im using only local data from my local database

Comment: ok in theory you could override `createHandler` method in your custom `AQH` but imho it doesn't pay off, why dont you want to create a custom `CP` ? i know that some docs say that if you dont want to make it "public" you can use directly `SQLiteOpenHelper`, but if there is an option to not to export `CP` it is for some purposes, dont you think?

Comment: @pskink I never worked with that because I never needed one. So I have no knowledge about it. And after reading some androiddeveloper articles I dont know how it works and how I have to implement it

Comment: [this](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-writing-your-own-content-provider/) is gut, or you can use [this](https://github.com/pushtorefresh/storio)

Comment: @pskink What is this library for?

Comment: its for easy accessing your custom `ContentProvider`